# How to get the values in an object if it matches input - JS

Tags: javascript

```
   export const flightsData = [ {
    id: 12,
    start: 'Manila (MNL)',
    destination: "Bangkok (DMK)",
    price: 10436,
    time: 210
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    start:'Manila (MNL)',
    destination: "Seoul (ICN)",
    price: 3809,
    time: 145,
    connect: [ { id: 77,
      start: 'Manila (MNL) to Seoul (ICN) ',
      destination: 'Bangkok (DMK)',
      price: 6284,
      time: 250 },
    { id: 78,
      start: 'Manila (MNL) to Seoul (ICN) to Singapore (SG)',
      destination: 'Bangkok (DMK)',
      price: 6284,
      time: 250 } ]
  },
```

]

This is a sample of an object that has a property that has another list of objects with it, now if the user set the destination from Manila to Bangkok it should show the direct flight MNL to DMK and the all the objects in the connect property

```
 const connectingFlights = flightsData.filter(flight =>
            flight.start === from && flight.connect && flight.connect.destination === to
          );
```

The code above only works if the connect is not an array i dont know how to display it all any help is apprecited

Comment: Requirements are unclear. Need more info.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the data you provided and expected result you want,

Here is the code snippet to achieve the same

```
 let start = 'MNL'
 let to = 'DMK'

 const connectingFlights = flightsData.connect
                                       .filter(flight =>
                                           flightsData.start.includes(start) && 
                                           flight.start.includes(start) && 
                                           flight.destination.includes(to)
                                       );
```

Output:

[image]

Refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2wq578hd/) jsfiddle which I have created for you.

Comment: Hello, I've edited flightsdata to be more specific with my problem. when i try to use the given code it returns me the error "undefined filter"

Comment: @DiegoSanchez, The above solution is as per provided data,  if you edit it then it'll definitely not work.

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different approach from the answer given by [@er-sho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514820/er-sho)
, I have my code and result below.

Code:

```
const connectingFlights = flightsData.connect.filter(
  (flight) =>
    flightsData.start.match("MNL") &&
    flight.start.match("MNL") &&
    flight.destination.match("DMK")
);
console.log(connectingFlights)
```

Result:

```
[ { id: 13,
    start: 'Manila (MNL) to Seoul (ICN) ',
    destination: 'Bangkok (DMK)',
    price: 6284,
    time: 250 },
  { id: 14,
    start: 'Manila (MNL) to Seoul (ICN) to Singapore (SG)',
    destination: 'Bangkok (DMK)',
    price: 6284,
    time: 250 } ]
```

Comment: Hello, I've edited flightsdata to be more specific with my problem. when i try to use the given code it returns me the error "undefined filter"